# PHP: HTML inside gettext function string

Tags: php, html, gettext

I'm somewhat of confused. As far as I knew every text in a gettext function is used as msgid

So this one:

```
_("My long text that I <br> because I need to ")
```

should be:

```
#: htdocs/index.php:8
msgid "My long text that I <br> because I need to"
msgstr "Translation needs different <br> inside because russian is different"
```

I just can't find any documentation that gettext() or _() strips html tags out.

Should I be replacing it like this? And why?

```
sprintf(_("My long text that I %s because I need to "), '<br>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both would work okay, gettext does not string anything out of the messags. You might however want to not include HTML in translations to make translators life easier - it is easier to just translate string and don't have to care about HTML markup. Of course sometimes it is not really possible...

Comment: the problem is, that it actually filters my html tags. So the msgid is `msgid "My long text that I because I need to"`

Comment: What do you use for extracting messages? We use standard xgettext at phpMyAdmin and it keeps [html correctly](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/po/cs.po#L1890)

Comment: We use PoEdit for Mac and i'm still searching why HTML gets ripped

Comment: And what do you use for extracting messages from PHP files?

Comment: we use PoEdit for extraction and translating text

Comment: Then I'd say PoEdit is broken here, try using xgettext instead, it should fix your problem.

Comment: I think PoEdit uses xgettext. If you look in the settings it says "Parser command - xgettext --language=PHP --force-po -o %o %C %K %F"

Comment: You can try running xgettext manually if that differs from what you get inside PoEdit.

Comment: checked in other examples, and it must be the tool console works fine... thx